# Creating a new window that has a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hey Im trying to to learn JavaScript at the moment, and I want to be able to create a button on a page that I created in JavaScript, but it always adds the button to index.html instead. Please note I am running this off of WebStorm IDE and don't have a URL/ dont know what to put for window.open(____) because of that.

It successfully creates a new window saying "Hello", but there is no button.

```
var myWindow=window.open('');
myWindow.document.write('Hello');
var button=myWindow.document.createElement("newbutton");
button.onclick= function(){
  alert("blabla");
};
var buttonParent= myWindow.document.getElementById("buttonParent");
buttonParent.appendChild(button)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're creating a new window called myWindow, and writing the text hello to it. However, the container with the id "buttonParent" does not reside within the new window, but rather the document that index.html is in.

Try this out:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");      
newDiv.id = "newButtonParent" //make sure you pick a unique id      
myWindow.document.appendChild(newDiv);    
var buttonParent= myWindow.document.getElementById("newButtonParent");     
buttonParent.appendChild(button);
```

Edit: Fixed a typo. From:

```
var buttonParent= myWindow.document.getElementById("buttonParent");
```

to

```
var buttonParent= myWindow.document.getElementById("newButtonParent");
```

Answer (score 1):

When was the element with the ID *buttonParent* created? If this is your entire snippet, you'd first need to create that element as well, otherwise [`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) isn't going to find anything in the new window, meaning [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) won't work properly.

The other thing to note is that `alert` is a property of the `window` object, so just calling `alert('!')` will attach the alert the the main window. You need to call it as `myWindow.alert('!')` to have it fire on the new window.

Also, [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) takes a tag name, so if you want default button behaviour it should be

```
myWindow.document.createElement('button');
```

Here's a working example. I've set the background of the container element to red so you can see it is there.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/rohaje/1/edit?html,js,output)</kbd> - (Click the run button.)

```
var w = window.open(''),
button = w.document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'My Button';

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  w.alert('!');
});

var container = w.document.createElement('div');
container.id = 'buttonParent';
container.style.background = 'red';

w.document.body.appendChild(container);
container.appendChild(button);
```