# JavaScript similar functions not working

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make 3 buttons each that open similar windows.

In my index.html it is as follows

```
<li><button type="button" onclick="openBeep()">Beep</button></li>
<li><button type="button" onclick="openFlash()">Flash</button></li>
<li><button type="button" onclick="window.open()">Indexing</button></li>
```

My openBeep()

```
function openBeep() {
  var w = window.open(''),
    button = w.document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'Start Test';

  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    w.alert('!');
  });

  var container = w.document.createElement('div');
  container.id = 'buttonParent';


  w.document.body.appendChild(container);
  container.appendChild(button);
}
```

That script works fine, if i replace all the onclicks to openBeep, they all open new windows.. but openFlash does nothing despite being essentially identical.

```
function openFlash() {
  var x = window.open(''),
    button = x.document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'Start Test';

  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    x.alert('!');
  });

  var container = x.document.createElement('div');
  container.id = 'buttonParent';


  x.document.body.appendChild(container);
  container.appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: You're assigning a variable to `window.open`, and then calling `.alert` on that variable.. that works?

Comment: im guessing that whatever you have `working`, isn't working right because both the open windows are named the same thing.  that means that if you clicked openFlash first,it would `work` but then openBeep would not.

Comment: @Rooster I just changed the name in openFlash and it does not work. Further, if I replace the call to openFlash to openBeep on two different buttons, it still opens a brand new window... I also tried pressing openFlash first as you suggested, but it does not work still.

Comment: @tymeJV yes, just like calling `window.alert` since the result of `window.open` is also a window object (but the popup's)

Comment: @tymeJV [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) returns the reference context of the new window. You can see that this is code from an example of mine, from another question of Hugh's, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628308/creating-a-new-window-that-has-a-button-in-javascript).

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/jx5bj8an/

Comment: @JuanMendes you're right, on that site it does, but in WebStorm IDE it doesn't... strange..

Comment: @Rooster You really suggested that two local variables with the same name in different functions could be causing a problem???

Comment: @HughForric You didn't even try it in real browser first?

Comment: @JuanMendes I am very new to this, I don't even know how to try it in a real browser first. When I run it on WebStorm IDE it opens a new tab on Chrome via Localhost... I assumed that was sufficient. But regardless, I found my error.... I hadn't loaded the .js file containing the function! xD Thanks though!

Comment: @JuanMendes no, I meant the window name param because at the time I thought you couldn't open 2 windows with the same name....but after a quick jsfiddle I've been proven wrong.  I guess I need to write more js that opens new windows ;P

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip for the starting Javascript programmers: always make sure you have the inspector / developer tools open. In most browsers you open this with F12.

Then in the console you monitor all errors. Like for your problem (which you solved yourself ;-) you'd see an error saying that the function could not be found.